# Spring Boot with Webflux: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-webflux

I've tried to build a Spring Boot backend and connect my React frontend with it. In my local deployment, my API requests fail because CrossOrigin is not supported by localhost:3000.
I've inserted a "CORSGlobalConfig" to my Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CorsGlobalConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("PUT","POST","GET");
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this should work fine but something is not right. Do I need to implement my configuration somewhere?
The error looks like the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/REQUESTPATH'
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following CorsConfig to "com.package.project.config":

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/v2/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

And also adding filter (at "com.package.project.filter") for "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". They are all build up like:

```
@Component
public class AddControlHeaderWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        exchange.getResponse()
                .getHeaders()
                .add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Hope this can help somebody with the same problem!

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-header 
Config Source: https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spring Securuty take a look at its cors configuration. Similar to **bnexd**'s suggestion but natively injected in security filter chain

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .cors().configurationSource(createCorsConfigSource()).and()
        // your security rules
        .build();
}

public CorsConfigurationSource createCorsConfigSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I don't see a problem with your configurations.

But you can add the option OPTIONS.

```
.allowedMethods("PUT","POST","GET" "OPTIONS");
```

Comment: I've tried it with "OPTIONS" before but nothing happens. When I disallow "GET" it will not work and when I allow "GET" it receives the data. This just happens when I want to "POST" or "PUT". 
I'm not sure why this happens. But thanks for your help!

Comment: you've been trying to remove allowedMethods.

Comment: No changes... I don't think we have failed in our logic.